# Force div height to fit content with perspective

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use the technique presented [here](https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) to make the background of my website scroll at a slower speed than the content. I don't want the background to be fix, only slower.

Here is what the HTML looks like :

```css
.parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.parallax_group {
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 100%; /* <--- PROBLEM HERE */
}

.parallax_layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.background {
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/531880/pexels-photo-531880.jpeg");
  background-position: top;
  background-size: 960px 1000px;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}

.page {
  transform: translateZ(0) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="parallax_group">
    <div class="background parallax_layer"></div>
    <div class="page parallax_layer">
      <p>Line 1</p>
      <p>Line 2</p>
      <p>Line 3</p>
      <p>Line 4</p>
      <p>Line 5</p>
      <p>Line 6</p>
      <p>Line 7</p>
      <p>Line 8</p>
      <p>Line 9</p>
      <p>Line 10</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works at creating the parallax effect. But the problem is the div containing the background has a fixed size, 100% here is interpreted as the size of the parallax div, not the size of the content. But the content varies from one page to the other. If I give the background a fixed size then on some pages it will be too long and on others too short.

For example if the content has many lines it will overflow the background. If the content has only a few lines the background will be uselessly long.

I tried various tricks to make it scale to the content (such as flex) but nothing works, the background always has a fixed size. The only thing I haven't tried yes is javascript. Is there no way to do that in CSS ?

**Update :** I modified the HTML to show the problem better. If you run the snippet and scroll all the way down you will see that there is no background behind line 9 and 10 because the div displaying the background is not high enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the fixed background-size in the .background class.

I've created a snippet to test it and it looks like it works also with different images, but maybe if you can provide some dimensions of the image you'd like to set as background I can do further tests.

```css
.parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.parallax_group {
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;

  height: 100%;  /* <--- PROBLEM HERE */

}

.parallax_layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.background {
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/531880/pexels-photo-531880.jpeg");
  background-position: top;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}

.page {
  transform: translateZ(0) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="parallax_group">
    <div class="background parallax_layer"></div>
    <div class="page parallax_layer">
      <p>Content...</p>
      <p>Content...</p>
      <p>Content...</p>
      <p>Content...</p>
      <p>Content...</p>
      <p>Content...</p>
      <p>Content...</p>
      <p>Content...</p>
      <p>Content...</p>
      <p>Content...</p>
      <p>Content...</p>
      <p>Content...</p>
      <p>Content...</p>
      <p>Content...</p>
      <p>Content...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the issue. My problem is that the div containing the background has a fixed size, not the background image within it. Try replacing the "Content..." with a long text with many lines. You will see that the background height doesn't adjust to the text length.